# Remove a li element with animation not working when I am not on the same tab as the website

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, html-lists, removechild

I am using animate in order to remove an li element from my list. 
When I see my webpage everything works fine. But if I change tab in the browser for a while, and then go back to the webpage, then the remove is like not working. I can see all the element there. And I need to reload the page in order to start the animation from the beginning.

```
 var first = $("#myel li:first");
 var last  = $("#myel li:last");

 first.animate({ top: 0 }, 250, function() {
       last.animate({ top: 50 }, 250, function() {
            last.remove();
        });
 });
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance